# Replacing a string of text with another string using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string **Action - [N]ew, [U]pdate, or [D]elete : N** that I need to replace with "Action - [N]ew, [U]pdate, or [D]elete : U" somhow by using preg_replace I can't get it working. It remains the same.

My code looks like this

```
$action = Action - '[N]ew, [U]pdate, or [D]elete : U';
$line = preg_replace("/(Action - [N]ew, [U]pdate, or [D]elete : N)/",$action,$line);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[` and `]` are special characters in regular expressions. You'll have to escape them if you want to match them:

```
"/(Action - \[N\]ew, \[U\]pdate, or \[D\]elete : N)/"
```

Without being escaped, and expression within `[` and `]` will match one of every character within them. So in your original case, `"[N]ew"` was matching `"New"`. If it had been `"[NP]ew"`, it would have matched `"New"` or `"Pew"`.

Comment: Thx, this was actually easy, I had to know that, too much coding for a day ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need `preg_replace` to do that. A simple `str_replace` will suffice:

```
$action = 'Action - [N]ew, [U]pdate, or [D]elete : U';
$line = str_replace('Action - [N]ew, [U]pdate, or [D]elete : N', $action, $line);
```

Comment: +1 for an alternate, simpler solution. I'll let my answer stand in case his example is just a simplification.

Answer (score 2):

Couple problems:

**1) Syntax error in your first line. Your quotes are misplaced.  It should be:**

```
 $action = "Action - [N]ew, [U]pdate, or [D]elete : N";
```

**2) You need to escape the square brackets (`[` and `]`) in regular expressions.  Alternatively, you can do:**

```
 $line = preg_replace("/N$/", "U", $action);
```

**So combining them:**

```
 $action = "Action - [N]ew, [U]pdate, or [D]elete : N";
 $line = preg_replace("/N$/", "U", $action);
```

Answer (score 0):

try escaping the '[' and ']'